# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str In Socket Module

Tags: python, sockets, networking, webserver

I'm currently working on a project called Door(On-The)Floor or DoorFloor
And when I run it i get this:

```
Server Running on http://192.168.56.1:8080  
127.0.0.1 Requested GET / HTTP/1.1  
Sent 127.0.0.1 File: GET / HTTP/1.1  
127.0.0.1 Requested GET /logo-500x500 HTTP/1.1  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
 File "G:\DoorFloor\main.py", line 43, in <module>  
   CreateServer(port=8080 )  
 File "G:\DoorFloor\main.py", line 31, in CreateServer  
      data += open("assets/logo-500x500.jpg", "rb").read()  
    TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

And Yes I ran open with "rb" and I don't know how to fix this
The code is here on github:
https://github.com/penguinpolarDOTnet/DoorFloor
Only the index.html page will load I have not done to much on the main.py it's self

Comment: Please make this a [mcve].

Comment: As the error says, some of your code is treating `data` as a `str`, but then you are appending `bytes` to it. Pick one, for example by using `data.encode()`

Comment: @Passerby if you check line 33 of main.py it sends data.encode() to the client

Comment: That happens *after* where your problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this section of code:

```
data =  "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
if rd.split("/")[1] == " HTTP":
    data += "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
    data += open("index.html", "r").read()
    data += "\r\n\r\n"
if rd.split("/")[1] == "logo-500x500 HTTP":
    data += "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"
    data += open("assets/logo-500x500.jpg", "rb").read()
    data += "\r\n\r\n"
clientsocket.sendall(data.encode())
```

`data` is initialized with a string, then subsequent lines extend it with both strings and bytes. Hence `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str`. One solution suitable for a small case like this is to treat all your strings as bytes:

```
data = bytearray(b"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n")
if rd.split("/")[1] == " HTTP":
    data += b"Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
    data += open("index.html", "rb").read()
    data += b"\r\n\r\n"
# etc.
```

Note that you can't read the jpg in text mode.